# jquery text after element if

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code.

```
<input type=".." checked="checked" /><label>text</label> text *
<input type=".." checked="checked" /><label>text</label> text
....
```

And I want if is after a legend: "*" result will be:

```
<div class="star"><input type=".." checked="checked"><label>text</label> text *</div>
<input type=".." checked="checked" /><label>text</label> text
...
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to get the *. And how to wrap < div >

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery you tried.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for an implementation, rather than asking for help with a specific issue encountered building an implementation.

Comment: What is `<input type="..">` meant to be?

Comment: Following @j08691's remark: please show some research effort, and post your attempt too.

Comment: Also, you appear to have confused [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend) and [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) elements.

Comment: I have no idea how to get * :(

Comment: Changed legend to label

Comment: Closing as unclear to what you're asking

Comment: What is <input type=".."> meant to be? -- radio or checkbox

Comment: This question has been put on hold, so I cannot answer, but does this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8kT7/2/) do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) and the [CSS selectors documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) give you very powerful tools for finding the relevant elements in your page.

Once you've found the relevant elements, you can create a `div` and move them into it by inserting the div in front of the first one and then using `append` on it to move the others into it.

Example: Wrap the first `input` with a `label` *immediately* following it in a `div.star`:

```
// Select the first input with a legend after it
var elements = $("input + label").first().prev();

// Create the div
var div = $('<div class="star"></div>');

// Insert the div in front of the input
div.insertBefore(elements);

// Move the input and the label into the div
div.append(elements.add(elements.next()));
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/vaxiqutu/1)

Comment: Filter the `elements` with the filter-regex in my answer, and it's golden.

Comment: filter is missing on the star

Comment: @user3380605 If you expected a full working solution, you came to the wrong place.

Comment: @user3380605: I thought the star was just something in the question, not actually in the markup. That's why the above acts on the *first* match (the one the star is next to). If the star is literally present in the HTML, I think @ Joe's approach (which looks for the star following the `label` after the `input`) is what you're looking for. Or a combination of the two.

Answer (score 1):

I offer no guidance but this code and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dYyNC/

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><legend>text</legend> text *
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><legend>text</legend> text
```

js:

```
var star_inputs = $('input').filter(function() {
  return /\*\s/g.test($(this).next()[0].nextSibling.nodeValue);
});

star_inputs.wrap("<div class='star'></div>");
```

css:

```
.star {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```